# iReport 5 gives error while connecting to JasperReports Server

Tags: connection, ireport, jasperserver

I have *JasperReports Server 5.0.1* & *iReport 5.0.0*.

My DB is connected using *iReport*. But when I am trying to connect *JR Server* through *iReport*, I am getting following the error:

> Description: Unable to locate the server named "< em>XXXXXXXX< /em>" --- the server doesn't have DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in
>   the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name
>   and try again.

While at the same time, I am able to access & login to the server url through IE.

The same server is getting connected by *iReport 3.7.5*.

Please let me know where am I mistaking ?